# Android app crashing when running if statement on a spinner option

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner with Android Studio creating an app that will read from an API. I am trying to get the API to filter results using options chosen in two spinners; one option for a type of electric car charger and another for the max radius of results to be shown. The app suddenly crashes when it gets to the "if (defaultCharger.equals("0"))" statement. As there are no errors shown I have commented out different sections of code to see what works and this part seems to be the issue. This is here so the link will not include a filter for the charger type if one has not been chosen. Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class results extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String link, getLong, getLat;

    TextView newAddress, see, testResult;

    //Create spinner options
    Spinner dropdownone, dropdowntwo;
    String[] distance = {"Change the radius in miles", "1", "5", "10"};
    String[] chargeType = {"Filter by type of charger", "Under 2kW", "Over 2kW", "40kW and higher"};
    String defaultMiles, defaultCharger;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

        //text link to go back to home and enter a new address
        newAddress = findViewById(R.id.newAddress);
        newAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newAddress.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
                Intent intent = new Intent(results.this, home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //get longitude and latitude
        home home = new home();
        if (home.status.equals("gps")){

            getLong = home.gpsLong;
            getLat = home.gpsLat;
        }
        else if (home.status.equals("address")){
            GeoLocation geoLocation = new GeoLocation();
            getLong = geoLocation.adLongitude;
            getLat = geoLocation.adLatitude;
        }
        else {
            getLong = "-5.926437";
            getLat = "54.607868";
        }

        //drop down one - choose radius of results
        dropdownone = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(results.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,distance);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dropdownone.setAdapter(adapter);
        dropdownone.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //drop down two - choose charger type
        dropdowntwo = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(results.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,chargeType);

        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dropdowntwo.setAdapter(adapter2);
        dropdowntwo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //see if correct values are being returned
        see = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        see.setText(defaultMiles + " " + defaultCharger);

        //create link
        if (defaultCharger.equals("0")){
            link = "https://api.openchargemap.io/v3/poi/?output=json&Latitude=" + getLat + "&Longitude=" + getLong + "&distance=" + defaultMiles + "&distanceunit=miles&maxresults=10&compact=true&verbose=false";
        }
        else {
            link = "https://api.openchargemap.io/v3/poi/?output=json&Latitude=" + getLat + "&Longitude=" + getLong + "&distance=" + defaultMiles + "&distanceunit=miles&LevelID=" + defaultCharger + "&maxresults=1&compact=true&verbose=false";
        }

        testResult = findViewById(R.id.testResult);
        testResult.setText(link);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        switch (parent.getId()){
            case R.id.spinner1:
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        // Create default if nothing is changed
                        defaultMiles = "0";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // 1 mile radius
                        defaultMiles = "1";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // 5 mile radius
                        defaultMiles = "5";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // 10 mile radius
                        defaultMiles = "10";
                        break;
                }
            case R.id.spinner2:
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        // Default for no charger filter
                        defaultCharger = "0";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // Type 1 charger
                        defaultCharger = "1";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // Type 2 charger
                        defaultCharger = "2";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // Type 3 charger
                        defaultCharger = "3";
                        break;
                }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        defaultMiles = "10";
        defaultCharger = "0";
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you sure `defaultCharger` is initialized and not null when you are trying to call `defaultCharger.equals`? Have you tried switching the order of equals comparision to `"0".equals(defaultCharger)` to avoid potential NullPointerExceptions?

Comment: _"there are no errors shown"_ If the app actually crashes there should be a stacktrace in the logcat output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your defaultCharger String will be null in the onCreate method, causing a NullPointerException when trying to compare it : `if (defaultCharger.equals("0"))` .

You can prevent it by setting a value like "" for defaultCharger during variable declaration:

```
String defaultCharger = "";
```

or by switching around the equals statement:

```
if ("0".equals(defaultCharger))
```